# Connecting to SQL Server 13 with Java 17

Tags: java, sql-server

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server 13 in a Springboot 2.7.5 after upgrading java to version 17

This is the key points the stacktrace when the application starts up and attempts to connect

```
 Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: \"Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints\". ClientConnectionId:3dd8afba-ccaf-451e-a8f1-5687b548ee3b\

java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints check failed on keysize limits: RSA 1024 bit key used with certificate: CN={SERVER_URL}
```

I've tried to add `encrypt=true` and `trustServerCertificate=true` to the connection url and still get the same issue.

Looking at the SQL version compatbiity list: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-ver16

I should be able to use `com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:11.2.0.jre17` also downgrading major versions also get the same result.

I'm able to connect the server using the same creds using intellij thats configured to use java 17 and using driver `11.2.1`

Comment: I think recent Java versions disabled insecure RSA key sizes by default (although as far as I can tell, 1024 should still be allowed with the default config). Either you need to change your SQL Server to use a certificate with a larger RSA key (e.g. 2048 bits or more), or you need to change the security config of your JVM to allow those smaller RSA keys.

Comment: encrypt=true is now the default behavior (since 10.x) - try encrypt=false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue, since RHEL8 it has removed weak crypto algorithms. So, I had to update the Docker file to have `RUN update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY`, see also https://access.redhat.com/articles/3642912